# How to read audio device output(speaker) in python

Tags: python, ubuntu, audio, pyaudio

I was wandering through all the sources available for python audio library, but I can find sources only for input audio devices. I want to read the audio stream from output device using python in Ubuntu.

Comment: One way to capture speaker output would be to record audio coming out from speaker using a microphone and then process. You will need to factor in noise etc though.